# :hover animation with css content breaks in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm using viewport-units-buggyfill to cover `vw` and `vh` measures. I have to use `content` in css to create a good fallback, all works fine but, for a reason that I don't understand, Safari doesn't let me animate `:hover` if it the code has css `content` inside, here is the problem (tested on Safari 8/Mac and iOS8)

https://fiddle.jshell.net/nc9chuod/

Any idea what's I'm doing wrong?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  content: "not-a-problem";
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(50vw, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(50vw, 0, 0);
  content: "not-working";
}
```

```html
<div id="transition"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content` property can only be used in pseudo elements.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content:

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

This is likely what is breaking in Safari (tested and confirmed in Safari for Windows). Try moving `content:"not-working";` into `div:hover:after` instead:

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100vw;
 min-height: 50vh;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div:hover {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(50vw,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(50vw,0,0);
}

div:hover:after {
 content:"not-working";
}
```

```html
<div id="transition"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, that I know, but while I needed the content to use with the buggyfill plug and it works on all the other platforms I was hopping if there was any way to don't cause the error on Safari...I think I will try to solve it differently. Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no need for the content'' property as it's only used with :before & :after etc

I changed the :hover to margin-left: 50% and the same effect is achieved.

i'm not sure about using translate3d in safari as I've never personally used it.

check out this site if you don't know it for what browsers accept what. http://caniuse.com/

here is what i did.

```
div {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 20px;
position: fixed;
width: 100vw;
min-height: 50vh;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
content: "not-a-problem";
overflow: hidden;

}

div:hover {
margin-left: 50%;
}
```